# How to exit app on back press in a non start destination?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

Say I have a navigation graph similar to this:

```
---------      ---------
| Home  | ---->| Other |
---------      ---------
    |
    |
    V
---------
| Login |
---------
```

If the user isn't logged in, I've to show the login screen before he can proceed. As per the [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-conditional), I check whether the user is logged in or not in the `HomeFragment`. If he isn't, I open the `LoginFragment`. So far, so good.

But if the user presses back in the `LoginFragment`, I want the app to exit. But since `LoginFragment` isn't the start destination, it will simply open `HomeFragment` which will open `LoginFragment` again.

Currently, I quit the app by overriding `onBackPressed()` in the host `Activity` and `finish()` the `Activity` if the current destination is `LoginFragment`.

But this feels hackish. I guess this must be a pretty common navigation scenario. So, is there any "idiomatic" way of doing this?

Comment: I also have used `onBackPressed` in the login page on an app in the same way you are doing it, to effectively "trap" the user on the login page if he happens to land there.  And I don't have a problem with what you are currently doing.

Comment: What about using one Activity and having Fragments for Login and Other? Then you just need to `finish()` the Home Activity when `onBackPressed()` is called and the Login Fragment is shown.

Comment: The implementation you're using is the correct one in this scenario.

Comment: You can change the fragment without adding to the backstack, giving you the behavior you are looking for.

Answer (score 6):

I believe the simplest (and I believe the appropriate) solution to your problem is to basically use `app:popUpTo` and `app:popUpToInclusive` in your action which takes from Home --> Login.

This is a relevant example where when you move from Splash to Home screen, you don't want use to go back to Splash screen when he presses "Back" button.

[image]